# Is this a Ethernet LAN Splitter?

Tags: networking

I bought the following device from ebay, it is very cheap (1€ for 3):

[image]

It is advertized as "New RJ45 CAT5 6 Ethernet LAN Network Splitter Adapter  N7 J0W4". It seems to also be known as "B00UMX8FVQ".

When I try to plug one computer to it, the network seems (somewhat) to work, but as soon as I plug the second cable to another computer then both computers appears as if disconnected. So this is clearly not an ethernet switch.

If I open it, here is what I can see:

[image]

It seems some people are buying it, so I suspect this has some kind of use to people. What is this device for ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZLh2OHyOeM

Comment: No, it is NOT a switch.  It has no power supply, so no "brains" to act on the ethernet signal.  It most likely just connects both sockets in parallel to the one plug.  It will mess up the signal when only one socket is used, and  using both sockets will completely destroy the signal from both sockets. The only practical use with ethernet would be to connect two short cables together to make a longer one.  Won't work well, and maybe not at all for gigabit ethernet.

Comment: The most likely real use for this thing is to connect two ISDN devices to a single jack.  That will work properly.

Comment: Shouldn't this Q be on SuperUser.SE?

Comment: _"It seems some people are buying it, so I suspect this has some kind of use to people."_ - That's a non sequitur. After all, you bought it yet it's of no use to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

Now you posted a picture of the opened thing, I change my answer: This particluar device isn't an Ethernet cable saver but simply an ISDN 2-on-1 adapter.

---

That's a cable saver. A pair of these devices is meant to be put in a pair of wall outlets connected by a single 4-pair Cat5 (or better) cable.

These devices simply connect

- pair 1-2 of the plug to pair 1-2 of the left socket
- pair 3-6 of the plug to pair 3-6 of the left socket
- pair 4-5 of the plug to pair 1-2 of the right socket
- pair 7-8 of the plug to pair 3-6 of the right socket

or permutations hereof. It's important to buy and use pairs of those things as there is no standard which pairs are connected between plug and socket. The one thing you can be sure is the sockets only have pairs 1-2 and 3-6 used.

**Well, how does this work and why?**

Fast Ethernet (100MBit) does only ever use pairs 1-2 and 3-6. The other pairs may be used for telephone, Token Ring, **or another Ethernet connection**.

And the latter thing is what these adapters do. They connect the other two pairs to the usual Ethernet ones so you can use them with devices that have the standard wiring.

Another cable saving method is connecting a single 4-pair cable to outlets with two Ethernet ports and do this wiring trick inside the outlet harness. These devices cannot do the same again, so they wouldn't magically give you another fast Ethernet then. They only work if the individual outlets have all four pairs connected.

Also, this doesn't work with Gigabit Ethernet, which needs all four pairs.

Comment: you are totally wrong about it being a cable saver .... if you look at the picture closely, you can see that there is no crossover between pins of the two plugs .... the jack and the two plugs are connected in parallel ... this is a phone splitter that has all 8 wires for some reason

Comment: If your look at my answer closely, you can see the OP has added the picture showing the inner parts after I had answered.

Answer (score 4):

What you got there is not for ethernet

There are no "passive" ethernet lan splitters. You'll need to buy a 2 port hub. What is shown in the picture does not appear to have active power and in all likelihood cannot function as a hub.

It is not for ethernet, sometimes people use ethernet cables for other purposes.

Comment: [Here](https://lmntechnohub.blogspot.ca/2015/04/how-to-use-ethernet-splitter.html) they say that it is splitting 8 lines to 4 and 4, because Ethernet is using only 4 lines. It's just that you will need two of these to plug the same line into a router on the other side.

Comment: Devices that can be used to send two ethernet lines down one cable do exist but based on the OP's description I think it is more likely he just has a pin-pin wired splitter which is useless for Ethernet (despite the ebay seller's mention of Ethernet in the description)

Comment: @PeterGreen The description on Amazon is matching this usage: https://www.amazon.com/Network-adapter-Ethernet-Splitter-Connector/dp/B00UMX8FVQ

Comment: Well, and obviously it won't work for GigE link, as it is using 8 lines.

Comment: It would also mess with the matched impedance of the lines as two parallel transformers would halve the impedance

Comment: @laptop2d I don't think it will mess it more than any Ethernet wall outlet...

Comment: @EugeneSh. the description from that amazon seller is self-contradictory. The title calls it an Ethernet splitter but the bullet points further down say it has "parallel wiring".

Comment: @PeterGreen I guess the OP can just grab a DMM and test it :) Update: Apparently the wires *are* parallel...

Comment: _"There are no "passive" ethernet lan splitters. You'll need to buy a 2 port hub."_ - I think you mean 3-port hub ;)

Answer (score 2):

> It is advertized as "New RJ45 CAT5 6 Ethernet LAN Network Splitter Adapter N7 J0W4". It seems to also be known as "B00UMX8FVQ".

Unfortunately there are a load of sellers on sites like eBay and Amazon who are either ignorant about the products they are selling or are deliberately deceptive.

These people will put Ethernet into the title of any product that has 8 pin RJ style connectors, regardless of whether that product really has anything to do with Ethernet.

> It seems some people are buying it, so I suspect this has some kind of use to people. What is this device for ?

Based on looking at the device and your description of the behaviour I made an educated guess that what you had was a pin-pin wired splitter which is of no use for Ethernet. Your teardown confirms it.

Ethernet is not the only system to use RJ series connectors, they are also used for phone lines, ISDN and many other applications. In some of those applications a pin-pin wired splitter is potentially useful.

However sadly I suspect the majority of buyers of these things on ebay and Amazon are like you. Duped into buying it by a dodgy listing.

---

Footnotes.

- All compliant Ethernet hubs and switches are active powered devices.
- There do exist passive devices for running two separate Ethenet lines over a single cable by wiring two twisted pairs to each socket. These must be used in pairs, one at each end of the cable. In my experience though such devices look quite different from the devices in the picture. The ones I have seen look like a box with connectors in rather than like a one-peice moulding.
- Someone did manage to hack-up a 3 port passive hub for 10-Base-T but i'm not aware of it ever being commercialised and I expect it would interact badly with more modern variants of twisted pair Ethernet.

Answer (score -3):

This device will NOT work for splitting Gigabit Ethernet or higher, which use all of the wires in a standard Cat5 cable.  Lower versions of Ethernet, or other older networking protocols, might work, but it's not worth the effort in my opinion.  Just use a little powered switch.

http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-gigabit-ethernet-works/